# C# comparing types for equality, with those types as parameters

Tags: c#, generics, types, equality

I need to compare types in C# flexibly, for the purpose of testing types hierarchical relationships. My first try is

```
public class ParentInfo<PT> {  // PT = parent type expected
    
    public static bool hasParent(LDBRootStructs item) {
        var parent = item.parent;
        var rightParent = parent is PT;  // << this is the type test I want
```

This is fine but it means instantiating the generic parameter PT to a known class at compile time. I need it as a variable so I tried this instead

```
public static class ParentInfo2 {  // PT = parent type expected
    
    public static bool hasParent2(LDBRootStructs item,
                                      Type PT) {
        var parent = item.parent;
        var rightParent = parent is PT; <<< error here
```

but it complained ***“ Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'LDB.LDBRootStructs' ”*** and additionally I can't pass in the requested type as a parameter.

I can work around this by adding a test to each of my classes (each class has myOwnType virtual func which returns an int that is fixed for each class, just compare these ints), but is there an easier way?  I’ve been looking at GetType and related but it’s unclear.

I need to do this to create an interpreted DSL so it has to be flexible.
I’ve looked for previous answers to this (this is SO, they must exist!) but I don’t know what to look for.

***-- edit, realised just a way to get a unique id (string, int, whatever) from a class would likely suffice***.

Comment: re "edit, realised just a way to get a unique id (string, int, whatever) from a class would likely suffice." - make them all implement an interface with an `Id` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to compare an instance of a class to an instance of `Type` - that wont work (or at least won't do what you expect).

Compare the *type* of parent to the type `PT`

```
var rightParent = parent.GetType() == PT;
```

This will only match exactly. For a hierarchy/inheritance chain of types you could also use

```
var rightParent = PT.IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType());
```

Comment: This looks like the right direction but I still have the problem of passing in PT as a (normal) parameter. I can recieve it as "Type PT" in the param list above, but how do I pass it in as an argument when I call it: "var ok1 = ParentInfo.hasParent(this, TVDeclarationStatement..." complains "'TVDeclarationStatement' is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

Comment: @user3779002 `typeof(TVDeclarationStatement)` is what you're after I think

Comment: Aaaaand liftoff! Thanks, answer accepted. That will save me much wasted time.

Answer (score 1):

The reflection-based equivalent to

```
bool IsOfType<T>(object o)
{
    return o is T;
}
```

uses [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=net-5.0)

```
bool IsOfType(object o, Type t)
{
    return t.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType());
}
```

Comment: Other answer is more complete so I took that, but thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
        var foo = new Foo();
        Type bar = typeof(Foo);

        if (foo.GetType().Equals(bar))
        {

        }
```